# How to prevent rounding on the top and buttom of tableview when we have headers anyway?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view in "grouped" mode. I have header and footer that rounded the corner.

I want a line separator between each tableViewCell

This is the result I got:
[image]

I am better of writing the line separator manually. I wonder if this is by design,etc.

Answer (score 0):

In table view property you can find the `Separtor` property under the `Attribute inspector`. There you can change it.

Comment: I DID that obviously. Select to single.

Answer (score 0):

You add the following code cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate of tableView to create a custom image view of 1px height and 200px width for everyCell

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200,self.view.bounds.size.width, 1)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lineView];
```

Answer (score 0):

On the tableview set clipToBounds to no